# can't return index of values in position 0-3 in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

this seems like an odd one to me.  I have a script that runs through text files and for the most part works fine but a handful of files make the script throw an error.  The data in the file looks like this

```
start time = 0.016000

Time.            Col1.       Col2
0.000000.       0.00000      0.000000
0.016000.       -0.40000.    -0.500000
0.031000.       -8.40000.    -8.900000
0.047000.       -8.72000.    -8.770000
0.062000.       -8.730000.   -8.970000
```

One of the things the script needs to do find the start time and return the value in Col2.

I find the start time with a regex and check with a print statement which is always correct so Im happy with that part.

```
start = float(reg expression...)
print (start)
```

Then I need to find the index of the start time to get the value from col2

```
data_start = df[df['Time'] == start].index.item()
```

What I have noticed is that (using the data above) if my start time is in positions 0-3 (i.e. 0.0000, 0.016000, 0.031000, or 0.047000) I get the following error

```
 data_start = df[df['Time (s)'] == start].index.item()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 719, in item
return self.values.item()
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

But if the start time is in position 4 the same script (i.e. 0.062000 in this case) then the index is returned and the script executes perfectly.  I have confirmed this by manually editing the start time in a few of the data txt files. In fact it doesn't seem to matter what the value of those first positions are the ValueError occurs.

Really stumped so any help appreciated!

Comment: what's the value of `start`?

Comment: It looks like you have multiple rows where `df['Time'] == start` evaluates to `True`

Comment: try `df.loc[df['Time.'].eq(start).idxmax(), 'Col2']` ?

Comment: why are your Time columns named differently? we have `Time.`, `Time (s)` and `Time`

Comment: the different time names its my mistake.  I was trying to simplify how the data structure looked, the real data has Time (s) as the col heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is triggered when you're working on an empty array, i.e.,the result of

```
df[df['Time (s)'] == start]
```

is an empty array

Comment: Marked as correct.  I am reading the text files using pd.read.csv using white space as the delimiter.  There are a several lines of text that come before the column headings. Feel a bit of an eejit as in my txt editor they show as 7 lines (due to soft wrap I think) but in fact they are 3 lines.  I had skip rows set to 7 meaning the first 4 rows of the data file were missed hence I couldn't get an index.  Your comment about an empty array put me on the right track.  Thanks!